# how to compress the video size while playing or downloading into browser in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-video

I'm playing videos from the server but the size of the videos are over 200MB and the duration is 7 to 10 sec. so while playing videos are buffering so much. is it possible to compress the videos before/while downloading or loading into browser. I'm using ngx-videogular library. from api i'm getting video urls.

Comment: You cannot compress as you download. If you want to play smoothly on the internet then simply don't use one fifth of a gigabyte's data just for showing 7 seconds of movement. Can you change your settings in your video editor to output smaller files? You need to put smaller files on your server, because Angular code cannot fix this).

Comment: @VC.One is there any alternative way ?

Comment: @VC.One is it possible with service workers or gzip compresser ?

Comment: You can try using a tool called FFmpeg (by installing it on your computer) to access the online files. FFmpeg can re-encode according to your new settings, and it can send output to another location (_eg:_ your online PHP script)  where that same PHP will write the received bytes into your server as a new file. The result is a smaller upload with same file name (can overwrite or else maybe move the 200mb file to some "backups" folder).